# "Select distinct case when..." query conversion from raw PHP to Laravel query builder

Tags: php, laravel

I have a table in my database named 'messages' and the basic columns are `message_from,message_to, message`. I need to list the other users who sent messages to me or I sent messages to whom. And I am trying to convert a raw PHP query in Laravel.

Raw Query:

```
$user_id = 'my_user_id';

Select Distinct case when message_from = '$user_id' then message_to else message_from end as
contact from messages where '$user_id' in (message_from, message_to) ORDER BY id DESC
```

My Conversion to Laravel:

```
$user_id = Auth::user()->user_id;

$messages = DB::table('messages')
            ->selectRaw("(SELECT DISTINCT CASE WHEN message_from = '$user_id' THEN message_to 
              ELSE message_from END as messages FROM messages WHERE '$user_id' IN 
              (message_from,message_to)")
            ->latest()
            ->get();
```

But unfortunately, it's not working. I am getting this error:

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax;
 check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near
'from `messages` order by `created_at` desc' at line 1 (SQL: select (SELECT DISTINCT CASE WHEN 
 message_from = 'client-20220215L0pu1xDTy9S3SKf8055449' THEN message_to ELSE message_from END as 
 messages WHERE 'client-20220215L0pu1xDTy9S3SKf8055449' IN (message_from,message_to) from 
`messages` order by `created_at` desc)
```

Comment: Why don't you use relation instead of raw query ?

Comment: where '$user_id' in (message_from, message_to) ORDER BY id DESC - it will come like 1 IN (1,2) is that correct way???

Comment: I talking about laravel relationship https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships you check this from the official document

Comment: i know how relationship works....thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is wrong in your current query is you slammed the entire query in the `select` part of the query builder, which will not work because Laravel will try to build the rest of the query around it so will look like `SELECT (SELECT CASE...FROM...WHERE) FROM ...` which is clearly not the query you wanted it to perform.

Your query would look better like:

```
DB::table('messages')
   ->selectRaw("CASE WHEN message_from = ? THEN message_to 
              ELSE message_from END as messages", [ $user_id ])
            
            ->where('message_from', $user_id) 
            ->orWhere('message_to', $user_id)
            ->latest()
            ->distinct()
            ->get();
```

Note that I changed the `WHERE $user_id IN (message_from, message_to)` to `WHERE message_from = $user_id OR message_to = $user_id` because the other syntax can also only be done with a raw query.

Also notice the parameters used in `selectRaw` rather than injecting the user_id which may be dangerous (depending on context it is unclear whether `$user_id` comes from user input directly or indirectly).